# oracle change sign before and after column name

Tags: oracle

in mysql we use ` sign before and after column  name in query

i want support both oracle and mysql but in oracle ` not support and it most be change to "

is ther anyway to force oracle use ` instead of " for before and after column ?

for example this is my mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM `md_menu` where `place`='1' AND `adminid`='1' ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

but it most be change for oracle to this

```
SELECT * FROM "md_menu" where "place"='1' AND "adminid"='1' ORDER BY "order" ASC
```

is ther any way?

Comment: Use an ORM like SQLAlchemy, ActiveRecord, or Hibernate and they'll handle such vagarities for you

Comment: 'in mysql we use ` sign before and after column name in query' - unless you are using reserved words or invalid identifiers you don't have to - same applies to oracle. In this case you are using a reserved word (order) you should think about renaming to avoid reserved words

Comment: i kwow i most change reserved word.my main problem is sign.

Comment: Also note that in oracle, when you enclose an object name (table, column, etc) in double-quotes, your are forciing case sensitivity.  Thus, in oracle "my_table" and "MY_TABLE" are two different names.  But  my_table and MY_TABLE (no quotes) are both actually interpreted as "MY_TABLE".  For this reason, it's a really, really bad idea to be enclosing your object names in double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

IMO instead of forcing `oracle` follow `mysql` syntax, it will be easier just make `mysql` follow standard ASCI syntax :
add this line at the top of your mysql syntax, then the identifier change to `"` for object, `'` for string, just like `oracle`.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI';
```

here is some demonstration :

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI';

create table "a"
(
id int,
col varchar(1)
);
insert into "a" values (1,'1');
insert into "a" values (2,'2');
select * from "a" where col = '1'
```

also [db<>fidddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d90059b57938c5cc72ae58274bf4e21).

and I totally agree @P.Salmon mention in comment, avoid using reserved word as object name.

Comment: As @EdStevens mentioned above, using quotes in Oracle is generally considered a *bad* practice, as it forces case-sensitivity where it should not usually exist. *Every* reference to an object created using quotes will *always* have to be quoted too. Better not to offset your object names at all.